# How to access class methods after institiating object as interface?

Tags: c#, interface

What I would like to do is to have an interface like `IResult result = new SomeResult()`, and then depending on some `if`'s, access some specific fields after casting.

```
if (a == b) 
{
   result = (SomeOtherResult) result;
   result.fieldFromSomeOtherResult = 42;
}
```

Obviously now I can't do that, because `result`'s interface doesn't have this field, neither does `SomeResult` class, only `SomeOtherResult` class. How should I solve this?

Comment: How does `IResult`, `SomeResult` and `SomeOtherResult` related to each other?

Comment: `SomeResult` and `SomeOtherResult` implements `IResult`.

Comment: Being more specific (why `IResult`, what field, what are you trying, etc.) will help to get specific to your case answers. There could be an existing pattern already. Maybe use generics to pass `SomeOtherResult` type or perhaps it shouldn't be `IResult`, but a  more suitable interface (implemented by `SomeOtherResult`).

Comment: I think I approached it from a bit incorrect point of view. @Dai's answer helped me realise something, so I've checkmarked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using C# 7.0 or later, use the `is` operator:

```
IResult result = new SomeResult();

if( a == b )
{
    if( result is SomeResult someResult )
    {
        someResult.fieldFromSomeOtherResult = 42;
    }
    else if( result is SomeOtherResult someOtherResult )
    {
        someOtherResult.x = 123;
    }
}
```

That said, if you're initializing `IResult result` using an explicit `new SomeResult()` then you should declare `result` with the `SomeResult` type.

Comment: To be precise, `is` operator for type checking was exist before C# 7, C# 7 introduced a [pattern matching with `is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't like how the C# <del>marketing material</del> documentation refers to it as "pattern matching" because it makes me think of Haskell matching or otherwise implies (to me, at least) that it's an `O(1)` operation regardless of the size of the match's candidate expression list - when in reality it's an `O(n)` ordered sequence of type-checks - and that's *all* it is. I don't think it's possible for a language to have true pattern-matching without structural typing and value-typing (i.e. each distinct value, or set of values constitutes its own separate type) which C# lacks.